# selenium with python: driver.title is not the same as an actual page title

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a code on python that has to check if the loaded page has an expected title. But after the page has been loaded the line `print(driver.title)` printed out "Google" instead of expected "dog - Google Search" which you can find on the page source (`<title> dog - Google Search </title>`).

Q: why driver.title is "Google" but not what we have between the title tags ("dog - Google Search")?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
driver.get("https:www.google.com") # opens the browser
# finds an input field and paste "dog" into it and then presses "Return"
search_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
search_field.send_keys("dog")
search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


# waits until the title of the page appears)
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until
(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"))

)

print(driver.title) # prints driver.title (in reality it prints "Google" not "dog - Google Search")

#checks if the title is "dog - Google Search" 
if driver.title == "dog - Google Search":
    print("It works!")
else:
    print("NO JOB YET")

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected condition needs to be changed because `presence_of_element_located` hold true in this scenario as title remains visible since search page was opened so it doesn't really wait for title to update. Instead you should wait until text is changed in title to what is expected in expected condition as below.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"), "dog - Google Search")
)
```

This will poll the DOM for 10 seconds and if title match is found it will proceed to next instruction.

See the [Selenium docs on waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, You will have to use Wait condition for the title to be changed. Google will show search result as soon as you type. The program will not have window waiting till title changes. So you will have to explicitly wait for at least 1 second for the title to be changed after you press enter or the search button.

Hope that helps.